# oracle forms set_block_property to disallow deleting

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

In what block do I need to put the code below and what trigger to use?

```
BEGIN
    if :BLOCK1.TEXTBOX is not null then
        SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY ('BLOCK2', DELETE_ALLOWED, PROPERTY_FALSE);   
    end if;
END;
```

What I wanted is to disable deleting if the :BLOCK1.TEXTBOX is not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

It might be `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM (block1.textbox)` or `POST-QUERY` on block1 (if it is fetched from the database), or `PRE-BLOCK (block2)`.

Don't forget to allow DELETE if textbox is empty.

Or, you could use `KEY-DELREC` which would/might then be slightly modified as

```
if :block1.textbox is not null then
   message('Delete is not allowed because textbox is not empty');
   raise form_trigger_failure;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

WHEN-NEW-BLOCK-INSTANCE on BLOCK2